# How can I multiply list items in a dict with another list in Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with player names and their points, and what I need to do is multiply each list item with coefficients from another list resulting in a new array with multiplied points:

`points = {mark : [650, 400, 221, 0, 3], bob : ([240, 300, 5, 0, 0], [590, 333, 20, 30, 0]), james : [789, 201, 0, 0, 1]}`

`coefficients = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

So for example for Mark:

`player_points = [650*5, 400*4, 221*3, 0*2, 3*1]`

And for Bob:

`player_points = [240*5, 300*4, 5*3, 0*2, 0*1], [590*5, 333*4, 20*3, 30*2, 0*1]`

What I tried was the following but it didn't work whatsoever:

```
def calculate_points(points, coefficients):
    i = 0
    for coefficient in coefficients:
        player_points = coefficient * points[i]
        i += 1

    return player_points


def main():
    points = {"mark": [650, 400, 221, 0, 3],
              "bob": ([240, 300, 5, 0, 0], [590, 333, 20, 30, 0]),
              "james": [789, 201, 0, 0, 1]}
    coefficients = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    player_points = calculate_points(points, coefficients)
    print(player_points)

main()
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Syntax might be wrong for key `bob`.

Comment: Your description of the problem says you want the results in a new list, but your code calculates the sum instead of putting the individual terms into a list. Is the sum enough, or do you need a list?

Comment: the sum is enough!

Comment: https://hackr.io/blog/numpy-matrix-multiplication

Answer (score 0):

For list multilplication you can do

```
player_point = [i*j for i,j in zip(point['mark'], coefficients)]
```

So if you want a player_point dictionnary:

```
 player_points = {}
 For name in points.keys():
   player_points[name] = [i*j for i,j in zip(points[name], coefficients)]
```

Comment: Your synthax seems wrong for bob player, you may need to add a for loop if point['bob'] = [[240, 300, 5, 0, 1], [590, 333, 20, 30, 0]]

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that works using a for loop:

```
points = {"mark" : [650, 400, 221, 0, 3], "bob" : [240, 300, 5, 0, 0],"joe" : [590, 333, 20, 30, 0], "james" : [789, 201, 0, 0, 1]}
coefficients = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

for element in points:
    player_points= []
    for i in range(len(points.get(element))):
        player_points.append(points.get(element)[i]*coefficients[i])
    print(player_points)
```

This will give the output of

```
[3250,1600,663,0,3]
[1200,1200,15,0,0]
[2950,1332,60,60,0]
[3945,804,0,0,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is irregular which make processing it much harder than it needs to be.  If all the dictionary values were tuples, a simple dictionary comprehension could be used.  As it is, you sometimes have an array, and sometimes a tuple which requires the code to deal with exceptions and type detection.

Here's how it would work if the structure was consistent (i.e. tuples for all values)

```
points = { "mark"  : ([650, 400, 221, 0, 3],),
           "bob"   : ([240, 300, 5, 0, 0], [590, 333, 20, 30, 0]),
           "james" : ([789, 201, 0, 0, 1],)
         }
coefficients = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

player_points = { pl:tuple([p*c for p,c in zip(pt,coefficients)] for pt in pts) 
                  for pl,pts in points.items() }

print(player_points)

{
   'mark' : ([3250, 1600, 663, 0, 3],),
   'bob'  : ([1200, 1200, 15, 0, 0], [2950, 1332, 60, 60, 0]),
   'james': ([3945, 804, 0, 0, 1],)
}
```

If you don't want to adjust your structure, you'll need a function that handles the inconsistency:

```
points = { "mark"  : [650, 400, 221, 0, 3],
           "bob"   : ([240, 300, 5, 0, 0], [590, 333, 20, 30, 0]),
           "james" : [789, 201, 0, 0, 1]
         }
coefficients = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

def applyCoeffs(pts,coeffs):
    if isinstance(pts,list):
        return [p*c for p,c in zip(pts,coeffs)]
    else:
        return tuple(applyCoeffs(pt,coeffs) for pt in pts)

player_points = { pl: applyCoeffs(pts,coefficients) for pl,pts in points.items() }

print(player_points)

{
  'mark' : [3250, 1600, 663, 0, 3], 
  'bob'  : ([1200, 1200, 15, 0, 0], [2950, 1332, 60, 60, 0]), 
  'james': [3945, 804, 0, 0, 1]
}
```